# Disabling asterisk sip user

Tags: asterisk

I need to temporarily disable a sip user from registering to my asterisk server. Is there any other way to do that apart from deleting it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in sip.conf add following lines in user's category

```
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try it and revert as soon as I reinstall my test asterisk machine. I broke it last night :(

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob. The permit-deny-mask you suggested is working fine.

Comment: BTW, it can be in one line `permit=!0.0.0.0/0` 
It may be more useful, if you are sed/awk/grep ninja

Answer (score 1):

Simplest variant - just change password to other or add

```
host=127.0.0.1
```

(change dynamic to 127.0.0.1, so registration allowed only from localhost).